# Copy code from answer adds spaces on the end?

Tags: discussion, whitespace, stack-overflow

For example,

when I copy a code snippet from someone's answer on StackOverflow and then paste it into Excel or Notepad there are all these extra spaces at the end of each line.

Is there anyway to stop this happening? Or a quick way to remove this annoying spaces - I need them gone otherwise the VBScript compiler complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of Notepad, download and install [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).  It has a bundled plug-in called TextFX that among dozens of other useful things can trim trailing blanks. See [this tutorial](http://a4apphack.com/featured/tricks-with-notepad) for even more cool stuff Notepad++ can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox and really want to stick to notepad (I guess you'll use IE then) you can try a copy text plugin like this [one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-plain-text/) or similar
(I haven't tried it)